# I have a column with 7 different values inside. I'm interested in just selecting one of those 7 values, how can I query this?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a column named "Destination" in my travel table. Inside that column I have values like city, country, street.

I want to just select the values in country, how can I query this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: MySQL != Snowflake ... what is your actual database?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). *Code* includes your database details and sample data when you're asking SQL related questions. And as far as the question you've asked here, find a good book on database design. Properly defining your tables means you don't have to deal with problems like you're having to do now.

Comment: because you are show screen captures from Snowflake, I have drop the mysql tag. Also past blocks of code instead of pictures, ether wrap the blocks in triple ``` characters, or indent the lines by 4 spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `:` notation to navigate into an object:

```sql
select destination:country
from (
    select parse_json('{"country":"Chile", "city":"Santiago"}') destination
)
```

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-semistructured.html